# Contents of apt.conf erased by operating system

Tags: 12.04, apt

I have a customized /etc/apt.conf file. It has proxy information. It's structure is like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@ip_addr:port";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@ip_addr:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@ip_addr:port/";
```

Several times a week, the content of that file is erased by the OS leaving the file empty.

Afortunately I have a git repository with that file and I can check it back out. But I would really want to know:

**What process erases the contents of the file and why?**

My Ubuntu version is 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apt configuration provided by packages is installed as separate files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` so that it can be added and updated independent of any local changes you make in the main configuration file. It's the same idea behind sources.list and sources.list.d or preferences and preferences.d. Either a single file or modular in the directory works.

The best solution is to create your own conf file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` so you can guarantee that it won't be overwritten by package updates.

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99mycustomsettings
```

And then you can put your settings in it:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@ip_addr:port";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@ip_addr:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@ip_addr:port/";
```

Comment: If package configurations files are in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` why they touch the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file ?

Comment: It's the same idea behind sources.list and sources.list.d or preferences and preferences.d. Either a single file or modular in the directory works.

Comment: But why would the OS delete the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and not the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/xxx.conf` ?

Comment: The package manager doesn't delete configuration files. It replaces them with files from new package versions during their installation. This can theoretically happen to files in `/etc/*.d/` directories too, *if they existed in the previous package version*. The package manager *never* overwrites files that didn't exist in the previous package version (unless you tell it to). If you create a new file, you're pretty safe. On another note, the package manager renames previous, modified versions of configuration files and attaches a suffix to the name like `.dpkg-*` or `.ucf-*`.